# what can I do when receiving no-undef error on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error when trying to run the page...

```
import React from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";

const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef and `reactDom` !== `ReactDOM` - JS is case-sensitive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is a syntax error, `reactDom` is not the same as `ReactDom` can you try:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
ReactDom.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
```